# Computer makes weird noise

Tags: noise

It is a laptop and around 1 year old.  There seems to be two sounds, one possibly coming from vents?
Both sounds start with booting up the computer in morning, they stop after 3-5 minutes after startup.

Link to sound:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tz1wtsrbanoic7/sound.m4a?dl=0

**EDIT : New higher pitch sound, I am thinking it is not vent, but RAM/CPU/GPU?**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/07x1rix8v56so0g/Recording%20%283%29.m4a?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the fan. Do you blow through the cooling holes with dust spray once in a while? If not, give it a try (while the machine is OFF!). If you are not used to do that, do it now far from clean clothes because dust will fly around. Repeat short blows until there's not any more dirt.
Then you can try turning it on and listen.
If no change and there's any time left of the guarantee, go to the service ASAP because these parts can be surprisingly expensive when warranty is over and you must dip into your purse.

Comment: It sounds like more than just dust, like a "stray" wire being swiped by the fan blades.  It isn't clear, though, why that would stop after a few minutes.

Comment: When the machine starts, it tests all possible hw components, even the fan. Testing means rolling it up as much as possible here. After it's done, and the OS takes over the hw, fan is only required when (or it's not required with high speed until) the cpu is too hot so the fan can spin down.


As for the dust or stray, sure, hair may be there too, but simple dust can also built up astonishingly massive strings.

Comment: The "higher" sound I am not sure is related to fan, but could be. It is because the sounds does not come from the same location. I thought it could be CPU, GPU or something, because the high sounds tends to come back when playing game. Maybe CPU fan?

Comment: I have not come across a laptop that contains more than 1 fan but this does not prove anything, I'm not a collector or heldesker. On the order hand, there are two kinds of things in laptops that spin and can mur: fan(s) and the hard disk. If it were the latter, probably the noise would not be your biggest problem. Nevertheless, worth a look at the SMART data.

Comment: I dusted out the computer with air, but the noise is still appearing. Not much dust came out of computer though.

Comment: I added new sound track, this is the higher sound again. I am able to reproduce the sound by doing something quite CPU?/GPU? intesive. The sound is not consistent, it cant be vent imo? Basically it is like a sound that a computer would do when it is thinking very hard. I can replicate it by opening my Matlab and scanning through a very large dataset, basically scrolling up and down, so that my computer has to "work" do display the new data to me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/07x1rix8v56so0g/Recording%20%283%29.m4a?dl=0

Comment: Can you Boot the Laptop off with the cover off the bottom to see if maybe the fan is having bearing issues when starting up?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I checked the screws and how it is built. It seems quite difficult to open it up, also I still have warranty, dont want to leave too many marks. I have acer aspire v15 laptop just for info. I dont want to go to warranty yet, because I am not sure the problems is too big and also this means I wont be able to use my computer for couple of weeks, but I am programmer, so thats a bad option.